# Android Navigation Component not displaying correct action bar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a `MainActivity`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
    }
}
```

And nav graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_main.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/AFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/AFragment"
        android:name="com.example.actionbartitletest.AFragment"
        android:label="Fragment A"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_AFragment_to_BFragment"
            app:destination="@id/BFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/BFragment"
        android:name="com.example.actionbartitletest.BFragment"
        android:label="Fragment B"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" />
</navigation>
```

And `Manifest.xml`

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And `strings.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">ActionBarTitleTest</string>
    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text -->
    <string name="hello_blank_fragment">Hello blank fragment</string>
</resources>
```

When the app launches the action bar title is `ActionBarTitleTest` (presumably the `application` `android:label` defined in the `Manifest.xml`), however I'm expecting the action bar title to be `Fragment A` as it's defined in the `android:label` attribute of the nav graph.  When I navigate from AFragment -> BFragment the action bar title on `BFragment` is `Fragment B` as expected and when navigating back from BFragment -> AFragment the action bar title then reads `Fragment A` as expected.

Why is the action bar title getting set to the `application` `android:label` when the application launches and not the `android:label` defined in the nav graph?  I realize I can manage this at runtime by calling `requireActivity().setTitle()` in the fragments, but I feel like using `android:label` from the nav graph should be sufficient.

[image: AFragment at app launch]
[image: Navigate to BFragment]

[image: Navigate back to AFragment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` method.

In this case you should add navigation support to the default action bar using:

```
setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
```

instead of

```
toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
```

Something like

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph))
}
```

Don't forget to override the `onSupportNavigateUp()` method as suggested in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar):

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however this results in an NPE, it seems to be because I'm extending AppCompatActivity.  When extending AppCompatActivity setSupportActionBar() is needed. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @JohnasNellen what is null?

Comment: `ActionBar` was null, I included the root cause

Comment: I updated the question to include the full stack trace of the NPE.  It's when `androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:227)` is trying to access the `ActionBar`

Comment: Don't remove `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: Thanks, that does work as you describe.  Now `Fragment A` is displayed as the title when the app is launched, however from `BFragment` if I tap the action bar back button it doesn't do anything.  If I use the hardware back button from `BFragment` it navigates correctly back to `AFragment`, but using the action bar back button does not work.

Comment: @JohnasNellen Did you override the `onSupportNavigateUp()` as described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar)?

Comment: That was it, I didn't override `onSupportNavigateUp()`.  Once I did that now everything is working as expected, thank you for all your help!

Comment: I put my app in the background and change the devices language. After that I return to my still running app. Due to configuration change the system recreates my fragment. All labels get translated except the app bar title. Any ideas? Maybe a bug?

Comment: with this my toolbar back button stopped working.

Comment: @NoumanCh Did you override the `onSupportNavigateUp()` as described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#action_bar)?

Comment: No, I'm using a delegate for toolbar so overriding onSupportNavigateUp doesn't look better to me. Instead I used both  setupActionBarWithNavController and toolbar. setupWithNavController in my delegate and it's working fine.